# Make a border wrap around elements following different heights?

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend

I'm using react-photo-album to have a photo album on my website.

I was wondering if it was possible to have a CSS border wrap around the photos at the bottom, but following the sides to account for different heights?

What it is currently:
[image: what it is currently]

I was picturing something like this:
[image: desired result]

What I was able to get it to using :last-child on the react-photo-album--column class:
[image: currently]

But any attempt that I did just resulted in a border around the entire container, and not the individual photos at the bottom.

I already style the other sides with:

```css
.react-photo-album {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 4px solid #86afe1;
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding: 3rem 2rem 2rem;
}
```

and the container's HTML is available to view [here](https://gist.github.com/JasonLovesDoggo/2bd508183ff8db6bcc92f296c8d027eb) my thought was to target the last child of each react-photo-album--column I just don't know how to do the sides then.

Comment: Add the HTML code as well. There i no way we can guess your HTML structure based on an image

Comment: @CornelRaiu as I said I'm using react-photo-album so I didn't make the HTML but the bit that I did write is

`<PhotoAlbum layout="masonry" photos={filteredPhotos}/></div>`

Comment: And yet your browser still *sees* html, so please: right click the container element, click “inspect” find the correct element in the DOM inspector, right click and select “copy” and “copy outerHTML,” then paste that html into your question. Using React does not mean there’s no html, it just means it’s authored differently and via JavaScript.

Comment: @DavidThomas yeah sorry, just did that. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You could put borders around the side and bottom of the photo container divs. Then give these divs a background color that is the same of the overall background (blue), and overlapping these with the borders you want to hide. So basically:

- Your container divs have 2rem padding
- Each container has a higher z-index than the one to its left (to ensure overlap)
- Each container has a blue background
- Each container except for the first one has a margin-left of -2rem to move over the border of the container to its left

**Edit:**
Thinking this through a little more, this will only work when a container is shorter than the previous one. You could solve this by writing a function in javascript that checks whether a container is longer or shorter than the one  before and after. Based on this, you could use or not use a border at each side (by means of extra classes applied to the containers).

Comment: using the following [js/css](https://gist.github.com/JasonLovesDoggo/00459c32e983fbfa838e0fe7f30723d4)
I am left with something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/Fjr5EAM.jpeg).


the overlap doesn't seem to work, and I check the z-index and such and it's all correct.

Comment: You didn't overlap the divs yet, they are now next to each other with extra spacing in between. However, I didn't think it all the way through so I expanded my answer.

Comment: massive help, thank you so much and I'm only one step away, 
I have [this css/js](https://gist.github.com/JasonLovesDoggo/83943ad82564aba35211268c46f6a6f8)
 but the overlapping doesn't seem to work and I can't get it to overlap, I don't see the margin being overwritten anywhere in the developer console, any advice?  
my current result is [this](https://i.imgur.com/T4Umvwa.jpeg)

Comment: Have you tried the fourth bullet point, a negative margin-left/~right (e.g. `margin-left: -2rem`)?

Comment: yeah but it didn't have any effect, I tried with it !important but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I see your newly added screenshot, it looks like you only have a bottom-border on all containers. Make sure you add the right borders to the longer columns/sides (e.g. column 1 should have a border-right and column 3 should have right and left borders

Comment: I was able to get it to have sideboarders and such and that all worked fine but the overlapping wouldn't work I tried with the margin-left: -2rem !important But it had no effect and like I said I checked developer console and I couldn't see anywhere that it was being overwritten

Comment: It's hard to tell what the solution would be... If you share a codesandbox or something, I could have a look.

Comment: of course. the sandbox is  https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-benji-lpsmsy?file=/src/styles.css and please see the comment at the bottom of styles.css.

Comment: This seems to work https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-beaver-j1v4e2. All I did was remove `justify-content: space-between;` (and `padding-left: -2rem`; negative values for padding don't work). I should note that in your version though, the missing borders appeared as soon as I put a space/enter in the code of photos.js, not sure why.